# MySQL using JSON_ARRAYAGG in a SELECT IN clause?

Tags: mysql, json, select

Our database solution is very JSON heavy, and as such, our SQL queries are all JSON based (for the most part). This includes extensive use of JSON_ARRAYAGG().

The problem I'm encountering is using a returned array of indexes in WHERE IN, which simply doesn't work. From what I can tell it's a simple formatting issue where MySQL wants an () encapsulation and a JSON array is a [] encapsulation.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(si.ID) AS item_count, JSON_ARRAYAGG(si.ID) AS item_array
FROM sourcing_item si;
```

Returns:

```
7, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

What I need to do is write a complex nested query that allows for selecting record IDs that are IN the JSON_ARRAYAGG result. Like:

```
SELECT si.item_name
FROM sourcing_item si
WHERE si.ID IN item_array
```

Of course the above doesn't work because MySQL doesn't recognize [] vs. ().

Is there a viable workaround for this issue? I'm surprised they haven't updated MySQL to allow the WHERE IN clause to work with a JSON array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MEMBER OF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) operator does this.

```
SELECT si.item_name
FROM sourcing_item si
WHERE si.ID MEMBER OF (item_array)
```

Comment: It's relatively new, it was added in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: BTW it doesn't appear to work with nested items. For example:

        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(sp.ID)
        FROM sourcing_process sp 
        WHERE sp.sourcing_search_ref_id MEMBER OF
        (
            SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(ss.ID)
            FROM sourcing_search ss 
            WHERE ss.sourcing_main_ref_id = @sourcing_main_id
        );

Fails. It seems I can't check an aggregated array against an aggregated array...

Comment: If you have a subquery, why do you need to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`? Just use `WHERE sp.sourcing_search_ref_id IN (SELECT ss.ID FROM ...)`

Comment: The reason is I need to pass the array up the chain of the call because the root call references the embedded (nested) array sizes and values; so if I use IN it won't allow me to return nested structures for reference up the chain. Part of the challenge is creating a nested call that handles everything in a single call without having to go into the nest multiple times. IN just checks; but doesn't return a value. With MEMBER OF, I can pass a value up the call chain... correct?

Comment: Try using JOIN instead of IN. That will allow you to pass multiple columns up.

Comment: The problem is I only need to deal with JSON Array data, which is ultimately passed to our front-end client. What I really have is: SELECT A IN (SELECT B IN(SELECT C WHERE X))), but also returning the qualifying indexes of the B and C check without doing a join (because it's a 1:Many relationship). Hence the use of JSON Arrays (they are so efficient).

Comment: All those nested INs should just be a join between all 3 tables.

Comment: I don't see how that works. Table A has 1000 records which point to Table B which are 10 records which points to Table C which is 3 records, which points to a master table of 1 record. All I need is the Table A, B and C indexes in an array (separated, OFC). I simply don't know how to do that. And I don't understand why MEMBER OF (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG()) is failing either. If MEMBER OF (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG()) worked, everything would be perfect. Apologies if I'm not understanding your reference here.

Comment: Without seeing sample schema and data it's hard for me to be more specific.

Comment: In general, `SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM B)` can be transformed to `SELECT A.* FROM A JOIN B ON A.col1 = B.col2`

Comment: I'll mess around with this; I've been so focused on architectural work, I haven't really had to dive into optimization of nested queries - thanks a TON for your patience and response. BTW any idea why SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Y.ID MEMBER OF (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(ZZZ.ID) FROM ZZZ) isn't working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236464/discussion-between-floobinator-and-barmar).